# Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые или это устойчивые сочетания?

...в центре как грибы выросли улицы 48-этажных башен...

Снос старых зданий на берегу залива, экскавация огромного глубокого котлована с копошащимися на дне как муравьи строителями и цементация его стен открывали шаг за шагом грандиозность замысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...в центре, как грибы, выросли улицы 48-этажных башен...

Снос старых зданий на берегу залива, экскавация огромного глубокого котлована с копошащимися на дне, как муравьи, строителями и цементация его стен открывали шаг за шагом грандиозность замысла

Лопатин: Если имеются некоторые отклонения в употреблении устойчивых оборотов (порядок слов, подмена слов в устойчивых словосочетаниях и др.), то выделение возможно: А намосту, как черт, черный взметнулся плащ (Цвет.). — ср.: черный как черт; Нити древесные... Тают, как дым (Н. Матв.). — ср.: развеялся как дым;

Примеры

Под золотым дождем заокеанских долларов, как грибы, выросли военные заводы. [И. Флоринский. Против вандализма! (1950.05.09) // «Советское искусство», И глазки вдруг засверкали, и улыбка появилась, и грудки, как грибы, выросли. [Борис Васильев. А зори здесь тихие (1969)].

...перед глазами встала безумная картина: сотни людей, копошащиеся, как муравьи, роющие вручную бесконечный котлован [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)].

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!